# Make a webpage automatically open another webpage after a period of time?

Tags: css, html

Hey guys I have to do this for my coursework, here is the exact requirement I have

" After 4 seconds, a second page will be displayed (Main Web page). "

After I open the website a welcome page will appear after which (4 seconds) it will automatically go to the homepage.

Comment: Sure, do some googling on `html redirect`.

Answer (score 5):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4;URL='home.html'">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a meta tag redirect no javascript required

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4;URL='http://www.mysite.com/homepage.html'" />
```